# How do safely I add a raw string to a query?

Tags: sqlite, nim-lang

My SQLite query :

```
let data = db.getAllRows(sql"""
SELECT name, source, uploaded_at, canonical_url, size
FROM table
WHERE name like ?
ORDER BY ? DESC
LIMIT ?
OFFSET ?
""", &"%{query}%", order, limit, offset)
```

Nim adds single quotes to any string replacing `?`. I can manually build the SQL string and then use `sql(string)`, but the input then isn't escaped. Is there some other token apart from `?` that does not add `'`?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title question: *"How to safely add a raw string to a query"*, you can use [dbQuote](https://nim-lang.org/docs/db_sqlite.html#dbQuote%2Cstring):

```
import db_sqlite

let
  a = "unes'caped %' string"
  b = "my prefix ->"
  c = "<- my suffix"
  d = b & dbQuote(a) & c

echo d
```

This will print `my prefix ->'unes''caped %'' string'<- my suffix`, adding quotes before/after and escaping any ones inside. This string is presumably safe to pass as an sql statement. You should get the same result as if you had used `?` with extra parameters.